Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Undefined array key $result['is_successful']
Undefined array key is successful' in /vendor/magento/module-payment-services-paypal/Model/Sdk Service.php on line 122 in magento 2

Can you add full stack trace of Log ?

@Pinkesh Kuwal
Hey,
The warning you are encountering in Magento 2 is specifically related to an undefined array key in the SdkService.php file within the PayPal module. To address this issue, you need to ensure that the array key is_successful and is checked for existence before accessing it.
Here's how you can modify the SdkService.php file to include this check:

Open the SdkService.php file
Navigate to the file located at /vendor/magento/module-payment-services-paypal/Model/SdkService.php.

Locate the line causing the warning: The warning is occurring on line 122. Find this line in the file.
Add a check for the array key: Before accessing $result['is_successful'], ensure that the key exists.
Here's an example of how you can modify the code:
// ... other code ...

// Before line 122 where $result['is_successful'] is being accessed
if (isset($result['is_successful'])) {
    // The key exists, so you can safely use it
    if ($result['is_successful']) {
        // Handle successful result
    } else {
        // Handle unsuccessful result
    }
} else {
    // Log the error or set a default value
    $this->logger->error('Key "is_successful" is not set in the result array.');
    $result['is_successful'] = false; // Default value
    // Handle the missing key case
}

// ... other code ...

Get all your queries solved here. Thank You!
